# When wrong url is entered, exception error encountered

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I created a new Symfony project trying to work on following.

```
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle
```

Now, at the fos_rest.yml file I added following line of code.

```
fos_rest:
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json }
  view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
      json: true
  exception:
    enabled: true
```

Now if I try to enter the wrong URL then I am getting following error:

> Argument 1 passed to FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::getStatusCode() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\FlattenException given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_rest\vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\Controller\ExceptionController.php on line 68

Can anybody help me sort this problem.

Thank You.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "enter the wrong URL"?

Comment: Those which are not described in routes

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a current slight incompatibility with Symfony 4.4+ with regards to the exception listener. Stay tuned for some updates at the turn of the new year.
RE: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/2031

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of FOSRestBundle to 2.8

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle:2.8.0
```

This worked to me, I hope that solves your problem because I spended a long time to solve it in my project lmao.